# Attempting to install FSPS raises environment variable error

Tags: bash, ubuntu, environment-variables, installation

I am trying to install the python interface of the fsps program. However, when I run `sudo python3 setup.py install` I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Lea/Documents/HSCFA/python-fsps/fsps/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    ev = os.environ["SPS_HOME"]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SPS_HOME'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 87, in <module>
    from fsps import __version__  # NOQA
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Lea/Documents/HSCFA/python-fsps/fsps/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise ImportError("You need to have the SPS_HOME environment variable")
ImportError: You need to have the SPS_HOME environment variable
```

However, I have already set the SPS_HOME variable in my `~./bashrc` file, including the export statement. I have tried using the `source ~/.bashrc` command, restarting the shell, and also typing `export SPS_HOME` directly into the command line, but nothing fixes it. There was a similar question to this posted a while ago, where the poster's issue was due to the fact that they had not logged in as root when adding the environment variable to the .bashrc file, but they were running the installation command as root with sudo. I assume that they were able to fix this by logging in as root and re-adding the environment variable to .bashrc. However, this fix is not working for me, and I was wondering if anyone had any other ideas.I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that `sudo`, for security reasons, does not pass your environment variables to the command you execute. If you wish to do so, you may pass the `-E` flag to `sudo`, or specify it explicitly:

```
sudo SPS_HOME=$SPS_HOME python3 setup.py install
```

Comment: Thanks! What exactly does ```SPS_HOME=$SPS```_HOME do?

Comment: Running ```sudo SPS_HOME=$SPS_HOME python3 setup.py install``` gives the error ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 87, in <module>
    from fsps import __version__  # NOQA
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Lea/Documents/HSCFA/python-fsps/fsps/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    raise ImportError("Your FSPS version does not seem to be under git version "
ImportError: Your FSPS version does not seem to be under git version control. FSPS is available on github at https://github.com/cconroy20/fsps and should be cloned from there```Did I download it incorrectly?

Comment: `SPS_HOME=$SPS_HOME` passes your current value for `SPS_HOME` to sudo - it substitutes your current value on the right side of the =. It is the same as doing `SPS_HOME=/the/actual/path`, but since you already set SPS_HOME in your bashrc, it should be more practical.

Comment: It seels like `python-fsps` requires that `fsps` is downloaded with `git` to verify the version - you can do so by running `cd <your desired fsps directory>` then `git clone https://github.com/cconroy20/fsps.git`. You may want to move/delete the directory that you already have.

Comment: Thanks! But now it says ```File "setup.py", line 87, in <module>  from fsps import __version__  # NOQA File "/mnt/c/Users/Lea/Documents/HSCFA/python-fsps/fsps/__init__.py", line 44, in <module> raise ImportError("Your FSPS version does not have correct history." ImportError: Your FSPS version does not have correct history.  Perhaps you need to pull the most up-to-date FSPS version. Please make sure that you have the following commits in your git history, preferably with the last listed commit the same as your current FSPS commit githash: 6ad10,b5250,a23e4,45f96,05584```

Comment: I took a quick look at python-fsps' code and honestly, it seems to me like it should be okay, since these commits are in the history. Maybe try filing an issue in `python-fsps`' repository? They should be able to help you better with this.

Comment: Also, I've checked and the commits it lists were definitely in the repository when I git cloned it 20 minutes ago.

Comment: Ok. I will try doing that. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Yes, that's why I also think it's strange. But any further would get into debugging python-fsps' checks, which could get a bit more complex. Glad to help! If you can, please accept the answer for the initial environment variable problem.

Comment: In case it changes anything, I did check and the commits it is looking for are indeed NOT in my commit log.

Comment: I'm guessing something went wrong when you tried to clone it, since commit 05584 is definitely [in the master branch](https://github.com/cconroy20/fsps/commits/master) (the other required commits are in the next few pages). You could try deleting the directory and cloning it again, with `git clone https://github.com/cconroy20/fsps.git`

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried that already and it does not change anything : (

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` is the culprit. Commands invoked through `sudo` don't inherit the environment from the caller's shell by default. `sudo -E python3 setup.py install` should disable this behavior.

Comment: Why does it not work to just open .bashrc with sudo and then add the variable? Also, what does ```sudo -E``` do exactly?

Comment: Also ```sudo -E``` gives weird output: ```usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V   usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]   usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user] [command]   usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-T timeout] [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]   usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-T timeout] [-u user] file ... ```. And it doesn't appear to work, becasue running ```sudo python3 setup.py install``` gives the same error.

Comment: I guess I should have been more clear. I've updated my answer to show the full command line.